# GCP to AWS VPN connectivity one way ping

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, routing, google-cloud-platform

I have VPC under AWS connected to VPC under GCP via VPN (Google VPN and AWS native).

`AWS Region A (10.10.0.0/16) <-> AWS VPN <-> internet <-> Google VPN <-> Google Region B (10.132.0.0/20)`

Everything works perfectly well when trying to communicate between VMs in region A with VMs in region B.

I have another region C at GCP (10.142.0.0/20). 
Only default network is used.

- I can ping both ways between VMs at region A (AWS) and region B (GCP).
- I can ping both ways between VMs at region B (GCP) and region C (GCP).
- I can ping from VMs at region A (AWS) to VMs at region C (GCP), but not vice versa.

I do see 10.10.0.0/16 subnet under "Network interface details"->"Route analysis" at region C VM

- No problems at VPN only static routes are configured
- 10.132.0.0/20 and 10.142.0.0/20 subnets is configured in AWS VPN and propagated in routing table
- 10.10.0.0/16 subnet is configured in routings at GCP

Any idea?
Tnx

Comment: Knowing nothing about GCP, I'm surprised you can ping C from A. A quick search suggests that like AWS, Google Cloud networks are [not transitive](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering), so you probably need to establish connectivity direct from A to C. In AWS the Transit VPC pattern is sometimes used, but between AWS and GCP I can't really suggest anything concrete. Suggest you edit your question to include a network diagram if this doesn't help, make sure the problem is really clear, and the text really precise.

Comment: GCP regions have different subnets, but can communicate perfectly well as long as they are under the same "network" (default network in this case)

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved - posting it here if somebody needs it.

The problem was with AWS Security groups which were not accessing ingress connections from region C subnets.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Google documentation I linked to above](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering)

> Only directly peered networks can communicate. Transitive peering is
>   not supported. In other words, if VPC network N1 is peered with N2 and
>   N3, but N2 and N3 are not also directly connected, VPC network N2
>   cannot communicate with VPC network N3 over the peering.

You need to peer networks A and C directly.

Comment: As mentioned in question I don't use different VPC networks under GCP. Both regions are under the same default network. This is why eventually it is working perfectly well.

Comment: Interesting, it works a bit differently from AWS.